# curl -k HTTPS url in Mac OS X Command Line gives Empty Response

Tags: curl, https

I have been trying to get a response from a remote server using curl with a HTTPS Url.

```
curl -k https://mymoviezone.com/verfiy -d un="zeus@gmail.com" -d pwd="goohoo" -d apiver="2.9"
```

But it gives empty response and my server doesn't uses a valid certificate,so i have added "-k" , but it still doesn't works.

Comment: Did you mean to spell verify, verfiy.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer Sorry ,I don't get you Cam

Comment: Your URL: https://mymoviezone.com/verfiy should it be https://mymoviezone.com/verify?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here that need to be resolved:

### Checking DNS

```
dig mymoviezone.com
```

I used dig and sure enough your website resolves (A Record) to an IP address.

### Just trying it in the browser without SSL

```
http://mymoviezone.com
```

Redirects to:

```
http://bennettbizz.com
```

Suspicious.

### Tried to see if the SSL negotiation is working

```
openssl s_client -connect mymoviezone.com:443
```

No response. Let's just try connecting a simple socket.

### Trying to connect to port 443 (SSL) using netcat

```
nc mymoviezone.com 443
```

This never connects. So...

### Conclusion

There is no server running on port 443, it is configured incorrectly, DNS is pointing to the wrong server, or a firewall is blocking the connection. The problem isn't curl.

Comment: Sorry that was an example url. I'm trying to connect to a local server.

Comment: In that case substitute localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the address.